# Condition in a self-made function

Tags: r, function

i am trying to create a function to check the NAs values in a given data table. However, I would like to add a 'condition' feature in order first to subset the data table.

```
na_check = function(table, attribute, condition){

  # Definining a potential list of NA
  na_list = c(NA, '', 'NA', 'NULL', '-', '<NA>', '.', 'N/A', 'n/a', '#N/A', 'null', 'na', '<na>', '#n/a', '-')
table = subset(table, condition)
      na_test = table[[attribute]] %in% na_list}
```

The problem is how to define the condition (I would like the user to be able to specify it like in the 'subset' function). For example,

```
na_check(dt, id, country == 'US')
```

and the table should be first subset as

```
table = subset(get(table), country == 'US')
```

and not like

```
na_check(dt, id, "country == 'US'")
```

where i would have to do first :

```
table = subset(table, eval(parse(text == condition)))
```

My goal is to make it user-friendly

Comment: @akrun thanks, slightly edited

Comment: so your `eval(parse` is not working?

Comment: It is working for me though `na_check <- function(dat, attribute, condition) {subset(dat, eval(parse(text = condition)))}; na_check(iris, condition = "Species == 'setosa'")`

Comment: yes, the eval parse is working. However, i would like to avoid it. The goal is to have the user specifying the condition without the " (Species == 'setosa' and not "Species == 'setosa'")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With tidyverse, we can use `{{}}` for evaluation

```
library(dplyr)
na_check <- function(dat, attribute, condition) {
   na_list <- c(NA, '', 'NA', 'NULL', '-', '<NA>', '.', 'N/A', 'n/a', 
              '#N/A', 'null', 'na', '<na>', '#n/a', '-')

    dat %>% 
            filter({{condition}}) %>%
             filter({{attribute}} %in% na_list) 
}


data(iris) 
iris$Sepal.Length[c(5,  25,  35)] <- c('NULL', 'N/A', 'n/a')
na_check(iris, attribute =  Sepal.Length, condition = Species == 'setosa')
#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#1         NULL         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
#2          N/A         3.4          1.9         0.2  setosa
#3          n/a         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
```

Comment: i struggle to have the line condition working but trying ( Error: 'as_label' is not an exported object from 'namespace:rlang')

Comment: @richpiana based on what you. showed in your post, I am getting the expected

Comment: of course you will receive the credit you have already helped me several times :) apologies I did not want to sound rude

Comment: @richpiana could be that your package versioon is different. (didn't see your full msg)  I used `packageVersion('rlang')
[1] ‘0.4.4.9000’`

Comment: you are right, i have an old version of the package, will try to re-install

Comment: @richpiana you don't need the parse_expr as the `{{}}`. would do the evaluation

Comment: by curiosity do you have an alternative to as_label (at work i have the impossibility to update the package)

Comment: @richpiana for that alternative, it would be `quo_name`